# Query string passing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass id=1 when i press a link.

```
**link**
**view/index.html.erb**

<%=link_to "Questions " ,:action=>"index" %>
```

i want to pass this id value to controller **app/post_controller.rb**

Please tell how to access that value also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= link_to "Questions", :action => "index", :id => 1 %>
```

And a more readable version:

```
<%= link_to "Questions", questions_path, id: 1 %>
```

However, there's propably a much better way for what you want to achieve. If you want to link to a certain Question, you should do it like this: First you retrieve the question object in your controller like this:

```
@question = Question.find(2) # or params[:id]
```

and then in your view you just do this:

```
<%= link_to "Question", @question %>
```